# Numpy 2d Array slicing different elements from each row

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

Lets say i have a 2D numpy array

```
a= [[1,2,3]
    [4,5,6]]
```

i can slice it to select 2 elements form each row:

```
a[:,0:2]

Output:
[[1,2]
 [4,5]]
```

but how can i slice different rows individually with different lengths, like 3 elements from first row and two from second

Comment: You cannot have an array with different lengths in one dimension

Comment: @mozway, I think the question refers to slices capturing different amount of items per row, not to slice the whole row for rows of different lengths.

Comment: @Ignatius OP should provide an example for clarity, but it seems that a loop will be required

Comment: There are for loops to do that. Even if it where possible to do that with slicing (I don't think so), it would be at least terrible code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two separate 1D arrays by:

```py
a[0][:3], a[1][:2]
```

**But you cannot make a `2D array` with two 1D arrays of different sizes. Note that arrays in numpy are matrices, not 2D lists like Python lists.**

On the other hand, you can get a different slice but the same size of each row and make them as a 2D array. For example, assume you have the following 2D array:

```py
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]])
```

Now you can select, for example, three elements from the 1st row and three elements from the 2nd row but in a different position:

```py
a[0][:3], a[1][2:5]
```

Then you can combine them to make a new 2D array:

```py
np.vstack((a[0][:3], a[1][2:5]))
```

And the result would be:

```py
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 8,  9, 10]])
```

And if you want to replace columns and rows you can use `transpose` or `T`:

```py
np.vstack((a[0][:3], a[1][2:5])).T
```

Then you have:

```py
array([[ 1,  8],
       [ 2,  9],
       [ 3, 10]])
```

- You also can make a new 1D array with the combination of these two arrays:

```py
np.hstack((a[0][:3], a[1][2:5]))
```

And result is:

```py
array([ 1,  2,  3,  8,  9, 10])
```